# Class Mage_Facebookilike_Helper_Data not found

Tags: admin, helper, class, app

When i click magento adminpenal's `system>configuration` The Error will caused.....

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Facebookilike_Helper_Data' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

Comment: Which custom extension you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

As per your error it looks like your Facebookilike Helper file is not getting 
loaded properly. Generally this issue occurs when the Helper is not defined properly in the config file.

Please recheck it once this might be the cause.

Mage_**Facebookilike**_Helper_Data -> Mage_**Facebooklike**_Helper_Data

Answer (score 0):

I think in your extension/ code you are accessing a helper which is not defined like

```
Mage::helper('facebookilike')->anyCustomFunction() ;
```

So try to find out this type of code or declare the helper in your own config.xml of that extension as

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <facebookilike>
            <class>Mage_Facebookilike_Helper</class>
        </facebookilike>
    </helpers>
</global>
```